# Android - Blocking Calls, Voicemails, and Notifications

Tags: android, phone

I have an android phone. Over the last few years I have been getting multiple calls a day from spoofed numbers. Spoofed meaning they have my area code or a geographically nearby area code. Up till now I have been using free call blockers from the google play store. That helps a bit as I can block all calls from numbers not in my contacts list but it doesn't do anything for voicemail and the spam/scam calls do occasionally leave a voicemail. That means eventually they fill up my mailbox and I have to delete them (very annoying). Additionally, although the free call blockers work they still make an audible notification noise if you are say listening to music on your phone. The notification sound is quite jarring and distracting.

In this day of spam/scam/nuisance calls, does an application exist that can do any (preferably all) of the following:

1. Block the call without ANY notification at all (no sound, no lights, no vibrating, nothing)
2. Prevent the blocked caller from leaving a voicemail. As in, they have no opportunity to record anything.
3. Block calls based on area code